What historical circumstances led the two Popes to declare the 2 dogmas of Mary with the rare infallible pronouncements?
Most people think that Papal Apostolic Constitutions (which have higher level of authority than most other types of papal documents) are infallible, but in fact only Papal ex cathedra statements having 4 characteristics are infallible (see the Necessary Conditions section here):

Exercising role as the supreme teacher, not simply as private theologian
On a matter of faith or morals, not on practical or disciplinary matters
Makes an explicit declaration of his intention to define a doctrine Catholics are obligated to assent
Makes clear that ALL Catholics, including in all future ages are bound in conscience to this teaching

and there have been only 2 instances of this faculty being used, namely for the dogmas of the:

Immaculate Conception of Mary (1854, Ineffabilis Deus by Pope Bl. Pius IX)
Assumption of Mary (1950, Munificentissimus Deus by Pope Pius XII)

which were defined and taught through an ex cathedra Apostolic Constitution.
Why the two Popes found it expedient to declare the 2 dogmas of Mary using the rare facility of infallible pronouncements (i.e. ex cathedra)?
I'm primarily interested in the historical situations which must have contributed to the (first?) use of this facility for a Pope to personally teach infallibly.  Why wouldn't the two Popes use a less authoritative vehicle (such as a regular Apostolic Constitution or through a canon of an ecumenical council)?  Was there an urgent "heresy" to be dealt with, as it was during the early days of the Protestant Reformation by the Council of Trent?  Even if it was urgent, surely a non-ex cathedra pronouncement wouldn't be less dogmatic for Catholics?  Also, given debate in previous centuries regarding the Immaculate Conception, wouldn't a council be a more appropriate venue for the dogma to be clarified by the whole Church?

P.S. Impact on ecumenism
Now that Vatican II is almost 60 years behind us, the issue of the infallibility of the Pope and these 2 infallible Marian dogmas remained the top reasons why Protestants are hesitant to convert because they would like to see that all that are necessary to be believed need to have an explicit Biblical basis like every proposition in the Apostle's Creed, for instance.
(Just to clarify, sola scriptura does NOT say Tradition does NOT have a role, only that Scripture has to NORM Tradition.  So as a Protestant who is not a Biblicist / proponent of "naked scripture" I can also say that although the 2 dogmas don't have explicit support, they are not inherently condemned by Scripture either.  For example, even Elijah had his assumption to heaven, and Jesus was immaculately conceived.  So I acknowledge that the reasons that most Protestants adduced are largely irrelevant to Catholic way of constructing dogmas, which look to both Scripture and Tradition, with her own hermeneutical principle to interpret Scripture.  But STILL, I agree with the Protestant principle that doctrines that do not have explicit support should be optional, such as baptismal regeneration or the nature of the Eucharist, which Protestants regard as less essential than the Trinity, which has become the basis for ecumenism among Protestants.)
But history has shown in the past 150 years or so, that both Papal infallibility and Marian dogmas has remained THE single most persistent barrier of entry for MOST Protestants to "come back" to the Catholic fold (now more than justification by faith alone, for a hint see 2017 Pew Research Survey, 7% and 9% respectively). Because Catholicism elevates them to the status of "required" on the same level of the Trinity!  So it seems less prudent (ecumenically) in the age of ecumenism especially since Vatican II that embrace adherents of other religions with its inclusive language regarding the fate of non-Catholic adherents (cf Lumen Gentium) and designate Protestants as "ecclesial communities" rather than heretics who are anathema, to clarify the 2 Marian teachings as two infallible dogmas using the ex cathedra personal pronouncements by the two Popes.  To Protestants, it's a "double whammy".  Surely both Popes realized this?  Why incur the unnecessary ecumenical cost when a non-ex cathedra pronouncement PLUS a council document would have sufficed to clarify the matters for Catholics?
Yes, the historical time is opportune to clarify the Marian dogmas (as Ken Graham pointed out in his answer), but what historical situation made it expedient to clarify the dogmas using the ex-cathedra facility?  It's not as though there was an intra-controversy within the Catholic church that risk rupturing the church like the Arian / Donatist controversies, for instance.  Or the situation leading to Council of Ephesus declaring that Mary is theotokos which Protestants DO affirm and consider it as an important support (against heresies) for proper understanding of the Incarnation (see Gavin Ortlund's arguing for it).  Was it necessary for Catholics to have the matters clarified ex cathedra?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

What historical circumstances led the two Popes to declare the two dogmas of Mary with the rare infallible pronouncements?
The two Marian Dogmas in question are the Immaculate Conception in 1854 by Pope Pius IX and the Assumption of Mary, body and soul, into heaven, by Pope Pius XII in 1950.
Before the infallible statements of these two Marian Dogmas, the idea of Mary’s Immaculate Conception and her Assumption into heaven were hotly debated by Catholic theologians for centuries. It has only been recent, historically speaking, that the Church thought it opportune to define these two dogmas in an infallible manner.
Let us start with the Immaculate Conception.
Just before Pope Blessed Pius IX defined the Immaculate Conception in 1854, he asked the advice of the entire world of Catholic bishops as to the theological question of Mary’s Immaculate Conception and if it would be an opportune moment to go ahead with this doctrinal subject matter at that moment in time. The vast majority of Catholic bishops were in favour of a dogmatic defining of the Immaculate Conception.
The Eastern Orthodox Churches have celebrated the Feast of the Immaculate Conception since the 8th or 9th centuries. This predates the schism of 1054. It was celebrated in the West in the 12th century.
By the 12th century, some Religious Orders were in favour of the idea of Immaculate Conception while others were against it.

The Controversy
No controversy arose over the Immaculate Conception on the European continent before the twelfth century. The Norman clergy abolished the feast in some monasteries of England where it had been established by the Anglo-Saxon monks. But towards the end of the eleventh century, through the efforts of Anselm the Younger, it was taken up again in several Anglo-Norman establishments. That St. Anselm the Elder re-established the feast in England is highly improbable, although it was not new to him. He had been made familiar with it as well by the Saxon monks of Canterbury, as by the Greeks with whom he came in contact during exile in Campania and Apulin (1098-9). The treatise "De Conceptu virginali" usually ascribed to him, was composed by his friend and disciple, the Saxon monk Eadmer of Canterbury. When the canons of the cathedral of Lyons, who no doubt knew Anselm the Younger Abbot of Bury St. Edmund's, personally introduced the feast into their choir after the death of their bishop in 1240, St. Bernard deemed it his duty to publish a protest against this new way of honouring Mary. He addressed to the canons a vehement letter (Epist. 174), in which he reproved them for taking the step upon their own authority and before they had consulted the Holy See. Not knowing that the feast had been celebrated with the rich tradition of the Greek and Syrian Churches regarding the sinlessness of Mary, he asserted that the feast was foreign to the old tradition of the Church. Yet it is evident from the tenor of his language that he had in mind only the active conception or the formation of the flesh, and that the distinction between the active conception, the formation of the body, and its animation by the soul had not yet been drawn. No doubt, when the feast was introduced in England and Normandy, the axiom "decuit, potuit, ergo fecit", the childlike piety and enthusiasm of the simplices building upon revelations and apocryphal legends, had the upper hand. The object of the feast was not clearly determined, no positive theological reasons had been placed in evidence.
St. Bernard was perfectly justified when he demanded a careful inquiry into the reasons for observing the feast. Not adverting to the possibility of sanctification at the time of the infusion of the soul, he writes that there can be question only of sanctification after conception, which would render holy the nativity, not the conception itself (Scheeben, "Dogmatik", III, p. 550). Hence Albert the Great observes: "We say that the Blessed Virgin was not sanctified before animation, and the affirmative contrary to this is the heresy condemned by St. Bernard in his epistle to the canons of Lyons" (III Sent., dist. iii, p. I, ad 1, Q. i).
St. Bernard was at once answered in a treatise written by either Richard of St. Victor or Peter Comestor. In this treatise appeal is made to a feast which had been established to commemorate an insupportable tradition. It maintained that the flesh of Mary needed no purification; that it was sanctified before the conception. Some writers of those times entertained the fantastic idea that before Adam fell, a portion of his flesh had been reserved by God and transmitted from generation to generation, and that out of this flesh the body of Mary was formed (Scheeben, op. cit., III, 551), and this formation they commemorated by a feast. The letter of St. Bernard did not prevent the extension of the feast, for in 1154 it was observed all over France, until in 1275, through the efforts of the Paris University, it was abolished in Paris and other dioceses.
After the saint's death the controversy arose anew between Nicholas of St. Albans, an English monk who defended the festival as established in England, and Peter Cellensis, the celebrated Bishop of Chartres. Nicholas remarks that the soul of Mary was pierced twice by the sword, i.e. at the foot of the cross and when St. Bernard wrote his letter against her feast (Scheeben, III, 551). The point continued to be debated throughout the thirteenth and fourteenth centuries, and illustrious names appeared on each side. St. Peter Damian, Peter the Lombard, Alexander of Hales, St. Bonaventure, and Albert the Great are quoted as opposing it. - Immaculate Conception (Catholic Encyclopedia)

Prior to the 12th century, the Early Church Fathers already laid down the foundation steps for this dogma to be defined.

The constant faith (tradition: paradosis) of the Church attests to the belief in the special preparation of the holiness of the person of Mary to bear in her body the most holy person of the Son of God.
Church Fathers:

implicitly found in the Fathers of the Church in the parallelism between Eve and Mary (Irenaeus, Lyons, 140? - 202?);

Found in the more general terms about Mary: 'holy', 'innocent', 'most pure', 'intact', 'immaculate' (Irenaeus, Lyons, 140?-202?; Ephraem, Syria, 306-373; Ambrose, Milan, 373-397);

Explicit language: Mary - free from original sin (Augustine, Hippo, 395-430 to Anselm, Normandy, 1033-1109);


Eastern Church:

celebrated a Feast of the Conception of Mary in the 8th to the 9th Century;

Western Church:

celebrated a Feast of the Conception of Mary in the 12th Century;

A record of the feast in the 11th Century in Great Britain; in the 12th Century in Normandy;

Record in many churches of a Feast of the Conception of Mary in France, Germany, Italy and Spain in the 12th Century (Bernard, Clairvaux, 1090-1153);


14th Century:

was noted for the opposition to the Immaculate Conception from some of the great doctors of scholasticism. The celebration of the feast was not denied though. The difficulty arose from the meaning of the universal redemption through Christ.

15th Century:

Franciscan theologians solved the difficulty--Christ, the most perfect mediator, preserved Mary from original sin by an equally perfect act of healing. Duns Scotus (Scotland, 1266-1308) explained that the Immaculate Conception came through God's application of the grace of Christ beforehand.

From 15th Century:

the Feast was universally celebrated; and christian piety introduced an oath to defend the belief in the Immaculate Conception to be taken not only by Religious, but also by non-Religious and at the Universities (e.g., Paris, 1497; Cologne, 1499; Vienna, 1501, etc.)

1854, Pope Pius IX, infallibly defined, ex cathedra:

'The Blessed Virgin Mary, in the first instant of her conception, by a singular grace and privilege of Almighty God, and in view of the foreseen merits of Jesus Christ, the savior of the human race, was preserved free from all stain of original sin.' - History of the Doctrine of the Immaculate Conception


Once the foundation of the Immaculate Conception had been define, the Dogma of Mary’s Assumption into heaven by the Church seemed a natural conclusion to by undertaken and it took less than a 100 years for the Church to make this pronouncement!
By promulgating the Bull Munificentissimus Deus, 1 November, 1950, Pope Pius XII declared infallibly that the Assumption of the Blessed Virgin Mary was a dogma of the Catholic Faith. Likewise, the Second Vatican Council taught in the Dogmatic Constitution Lumen Gentium that "the Immaculate Virgin, preserved free from all stain of original sin, was taken up body and soul into heavenly glory, when her earthly life was over, and exalted by the Lord as Queen over all things (n. 59)."

The feast of the Assumption
Regarding the origin of the feast we are also uncertain. It is more probably the anniversary of the dedication of some church than the actual anniversary of Our Lady's death. That it originated at the time of the Council of Ephesus, or that St. Damasus introduced it in Rome is only a hypothesis.
According to the life of St. Theodosius (d. 529) it was celebrated in Palestine before the year 500, probably in August (Baeumer, Brevier, 185). In Egypt and Arabia, however, it was kept in January, and since the monks of Gaul adopted many usages from the Egyptian monks (Baeumer, Brevier, 163), we find this feast in Gaul in the sixth century, in January [mediante mense undecimo (Greg. Turon., De gloria mart., I, ix)]. The Gallican Liturgy has it on the 18th of January, under the title: Depositio, Assumptio, or Festivitas S. Mariae (cf. the notes of Mabillon on the Gallican Liturgy, P.L., LXXII, 180). This custom was kept up in the Gallican Church to the time of the introduction of the Roman rite. In the Greek Church, it seems, some kept this feast in January, with the monks of Egypt; others in August, with those of Palestine; wherefore the Emperor Maurice (d. 602), if the account of the "Liber Pontificalis" (II, 508) be correct, set the feast for the Greek Empire on 15 August.
In Rome (Batiffol, Brev. Rom., 134) the oldest and only feast of Our Lady was 1 January, the octave of Christ's birth. It was celebrated first at Santa Maria Maggiore, later at Santa Maria ad Martyres. The other feasts are of Byzantine origin.


Some scholars argue that the Dormition and Assumption traditions can be traced early in church history in apocryphal books, with Shoemaker stating,

Other scholars have similarly identified these two apocrypha as particularly early. For instance, Baldi, Masconi, and Cothenet analyzed the corpus of Dormition narratives using a rather different approach, governed primarily by language tradition rather than literary relations, and yet all agree that the Obsequies (i.e., the Liber Requiei) and the Six Books apocryphon reflect the earliest traditions, locating their origins in the second or third century.

Scholars of the Studium Biblicum Franciscanum "argued that during or shortly after the apostolic age a group of Jewish Christians in Jerusalem preserved an oral tradition about the end of the Virgin's life". Thus, by pointing to oral tradition, they argued for the historicity of the assumption and Dormition narratives. However, Shoemaker notes they fail to take into account the various "strikingly diverse traditions" that the Assumption seems to come from, mainly, "a great variety of original types", rather than "a single unified tradition". Regardless, Shoemaker states even those scholars note "belief in the Virgin's Assumption is the final dogmatic development, rather than the point of origin, of these traditions".
Assumption of Mary

When Pope Pius XII proclaimed the Assumption of the Virgin Mary into heaven, body and soul, the Mass of the Feast of the Assumption of Mary was completely rewritten. The Mass of the Assumption, Gaudeamus omnes became the Mass of Signum Magnum.
The Ambrosian Rite in Milan prior to 1950, celebrated the the Mass of the Assumption with black vestments, but when it was declared a dogma of faith, the Ambrosian Rite changed the liturgical colour to white or gold if such vestments were available!

I understand the historically popular support for the Immaculate Conception dogma in question.  But why around 1850s it was an "opportune moment"?  And why Pope Blessed Pius IX's already consulted worldwide bishops, not decided to simply include it in the canons of the First Vatican Council which started in 1869, rather than pronouncing it through the Papal Infallibility instrument?

@GratefulDisciple The "opportune moment" simply means that time time had arrived in Catholic theological studies to go ahead with the dogma of the Immaculate Conception. In addition to the worldwide opinions of all Catholic bishops, Pope Pius IX sought the advice and theological opinions of the most notable Catholic theologians of his days including the famous Benedictine Abbot Dom Prosper Gueranger.  Catholic theology was ready to explain this divine truth in a clear and precise manner.

I think it's commendable to consult bishops and theologians, of course.  But the question remains: was it necessary to invent a new faculty of personal infallibility in the person of the Pope rather than letting councils like Trent / Vatican II to issue documents / canons?  Or using both the personal encyclical mechanism and the council?  Yes, it is opportune, but what was the urgency?  Vatican I and Vatican II were not far away.
